# Run a function or create a class application at startup

Tags: vb.net

I have a few modules and classes that I need to init themselves once added to the project.
I'm looking for a <strike>method</strike> mechanism to call a routine(or something) during startup, without explicitly calling it.
I tried the following, with the hope that being `MyInit` public, will be initialized upon start.
Optimization is preventing creation of `MyInit` until the first reference.

```
Partial Public Module InitModule
    public MyInit As New MyStart()
    Public Class MyStart
        Public Sub New()
            Debug.Writeline("Yes, init is executed")
        End Sub
    End Class
End Module
```

I have a few modules that can be added/linked to multiple projects; when included they provide trace, code verification, version control etc. The idea is that to add or remove, the main code need no changes.

It doesn't matter is if it's a class, sub or function: I want this to run without explicit call.

Comment: Why do you need it to be initialised before it is first referenced? What is the advantage of that? The optimisation seems reasonable to me. I'd guess (depending on the rest of your code) that there's always a chance that code would never be needed, depending what the program does / what commands the user gives.

Comment: Why not call it explicitly? Also, you can write a public shared sub and call it without instantiating the class.

Comment: You app can start from `Sub Main`. Do all your initializations there.

Comment: See also the `Application.Designer` (`My` Namespace, `MyApplication` partial class).

Comment: Thanks for the negative. I appreciate them when they make no comments on why, on a limited point of view, the question don't deserve to be here.

Comment: @ADyson I have a generic (code) module when added to the application, self-update the application on all our domain. During tests, the module is 'excluded from the project' and 'included' again after test. Yes, there are multiple other options, but, this is one click away.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Jimi for his hint
On each module I can add this partial snippet, extending `MyApplication` class and using the `Startup` event to do the initialization.
This can be repeated multiple times and `me.Startup` will be cascaded as needed.

The drawback: `MyApplication` is available on windows forms only.

```vb
#if TARGET="winexe" then
Namespace My
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication
        Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
            My.Application.Log.WriteEntry($"Application start {My.Computer.Clock.ToString}")
            ' init module stuff
            '...
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
#end if
```

***Update***

I found a very easy and straightforward code that works with all targets and not just winexe (forms)
The idea is to force the creation of the class at initialization:

```vb
friend _startup_init as new startup_init with {.name="test"}
friend class startup_init
  public name as string
  public sub new()
     '... do here your init, 
     ' in my case a few addhandler to hook the master process
  end sub
end class
```